# How to Join Eloquent and Query Builder in one query statement in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 queries that needed to join 1st is eloquent and 2nd is query builder,

1st Query

```
$products = Product::all();
```

2nd Query

```
$inventory = DB::table('product_warehouse')
->where('product_id', $product_id)
->where('warehouse_id', $warehouse_id)
->first();
```

How to merge this 2 queries into elouquent way ?

Comment: Is it a many to many (a product can exist in multiple warehouses) relationship that you have, or one to many (one warehouse many products)?

Comment: It will be One Product per Warehouse so One Warehouse with many Products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your usage of the query builder it seems like you have an intermediate table to store which product to which warehouse exist, but if it is a one to many relationship you should not have that table, instead in your products table you should have a `warehouse_id` which will reference the `id` on the `warehouses` table, as you said the relationship is one to many, not many to many.

So in your `Warehouse` model you can add:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

And in your `Product` model:

```
public function warehouse()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Warehouse::class);
}
```

Based on your table name, you might need to set the `$table` in your warehouse model to match that:

```
protected $table = 'product_warehouse';
```

Then you have many ways to fetch it, one of which is :

```
Warehouse::find($warehouse_id)->products;

// or 

Warehouse::with('products')->where('id', $warehouse_id)->get();

// to get the warehouse to which the product belongs to
Product::find($product_id)->warehouse;
```